# Backbone client does not assign an id to the model after POST request to the service

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest, backbone.js, client

I have a backbone client and python service. I want to be able to create new entries and delete them with the "delete" button. When I make a POST request to my service, it responds with the:

```
{"entry": {"Title": "-", "Description": "-", "Price": "-", "id": 5}}
```

But my client model is not assigned an id from that. If i want for example to delete him, i have to first refresh the page, so the `fetch()` method will update my models with the server, and then i can do it. That means that the model is sent to the service, it receives the id back, but does not set it to my model. Any solutions?
My view code:

```
app.BookListView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '.page',

initialize: function () {
this.collection = new app.BookList();
this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
this.render();
this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook );
this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render );     
},

events:{
    'click #add':'addBook',
},

addBook: function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = {};

    $( '#addBook div' ).children( 'input' ).each( function( i, el ) {
        if( $( el ).val() != '' ){
            formData[ el.id ] = $( el ).val();
        }   
    });         
    this.collection.create( new app.Book( formData ) );

},  

render: function () {
    this.collection.each(function( item ){
    this.renderBook( item );
}, this );
},

renderBook: function ( item ) {
    var bookView = new app.BookView({
        model: item
    });
    this.$('#BookTable').append( bookView.render().el );
}
});
```

//EDIT
it turns out, i somehow found the answer to the problem, but still don't know how to solve it. The problem lays in the way i parse the data from the server. Currently i parse them in my collection as follows:

```
parse: function( response ) {   
return response.entries;
}
```

So when i  request a collection from the server, my parse function works fine. But when i request only the single model from the server (as in the case of creating a new model or altering an existing one) it still tries to parse an array, which obviously fails and as a result doest not assing an id to the model. I tried to add parse function also to my model:

```
parse: function( response){
return response.entry;
}
```

Which makes everything working on a single model (it properly assigns ids to them) but now, when i request a whole collection, my collection parse function doesn't work and i can't view it.

So now it seems, i have to choose between getting a single model or the whole collection viewed correctly, I can't have both. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: where are you making the post request?

Comment: I am making the post request in my collection view, inside the function executed at button click

Comment: I found the source of the problem, but still can't solve it. I edited the question accordingly.